# How to use LookBehind in this case? I'm lost

Tags: regex

That's my string:

```
myclass.test() and(myclass.mytest() and myclass.test("argument")) or (myclass.mytests(1))
```

I am trying to capture only the openings of parentheses "(" that is not part of a function,

So I tried to start capturing the functions (and then deny this rule):

```
\w*\.\w[^(]*\(
```

Perfect, i catch only the functions, when I tried to use the following expression I did not succeed (why?)

```
(?<=(\w*\.\w[^(]*\())\(
```

Notes:
- myclass. never changes
- don't forget the "and(" 
- (?<=t)( < works fine.

Thanks :)

---

Temporary Solution

I will continue studying and trying to apply the "lookbehind" for this case, it seems an interesting approach, but our friend @hwnd suggested a different approach that applies in my case:

```
\((?=myclass)
```

Thank u guys.

Comment: In which language do you do this? Java does not support variable length look-behind. And the `and(...)` is considered a function also, right?

Comment: I think you can just remove the last parentheses in the look behind. It should not be there. So, try this one to capture the openings of parentheses that is not part of a function: `(?<!(\w*\.\w[^(]*))\(`

Comment: @justhalf already tried but did not succeed

Comment: Python also does not support variable length lookbehind. You must use other methods. And by "did not succeed", please tell us more. Is it an error? Does it run but doesn't accomplish what you want to do?

Comment: @justhalf doesn't accomplish (checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640447/regexps-variable-length-lookbehind-assertion-alternatives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused on what is part of a function or not here.

To match the following `myclass.test(` parts you could just do.

```
[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\(
```

Both of these will match the open parentheses that is not part of the `myclass.` function.

Positive Lookahead

```
\((?=[^)])
```

Regular expression:

```
\(          '('
(?=         look ahead to see if there is:
 [^)]       any character except: ')'
)           end of look-ahead
```

Negative Lookahead

```
\((?!\))
```

Regular expression:

```
\(          '('
 (?!        look ahead to see if there is not:
  \)        ')'
 )          end of look-ahead
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/wE1pV0)

You could possibly even use a Negative Lookbehind here.

```
(?<!\.)\((?!\))
```

Comment: I am not a regex expert, but wouldn't `\((?!\))` be sufficient? Why do you need the look-behind for a closing parenthesis? The string does not contain any closing parentheses followed by an opening one, does it?! At least, the result in your live demo stays the same after I removed the look-behind.

Comment: @hwnd when i use arguments like test("xxx"), should not work :( I just want the parenthesis that do not come from methods, so in this case enters the previous example.

Comment: @gehho test("xxx") :(

Comment: From your string `myclass.test() and(myclass.mytest() and myclass.test("argument")) or (myclass.mytests(1))` what parentheses should be matched?

Comment: @hwnd only 2, from "and(" and "or (", only those which divide the blocks

Comment: Try this. `\((?=myclass)`

Comment: @hwnd, basically, as he said in the question, he wants every parenthesis which is not matched by `\w*\.\w[^(]*\(`

Comment: @hwnd I never thought of it this way, thank you for opening my mind

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use variable-length lookbehind in Python, you will need to do some of the job outside regex. One possible way is to capture two groups, the first one will capture the `class.function` part if it exists, the second one will capture the open parenthesis. So you can just take those parenthesis for which the first group has no match.

In this case, we check whether the match length is one character (i.e., only the opening parenthesis), then we print the matching index. You can print the matching string also, which would always be an open parenthesis =D

```
import re
text = 'myclass.test() and(myclass.mytest() and myclass.test("argument")) or (myclass.mytests(1))'
for result in re.finditer(r'(\w+\.\w[^(]*\()?\(',text):
    if result.end()-result.start()==1:
        print result.span(), result.string
```

Result:

```
(18,19)
(69,70)
```