# preg_match negative lookbehind

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, phpdoc, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to parse PHPDoc tags with preg_match, but I'm having some issue with negative lookbehind.  I've never used those before, but it is my understanding that they're used as exclusions.

Here is my pattern:

`/\*\*.+?(?<! \*/)@access public.+? \*/\s+?function\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\(`

Here is my sample PHP file I'm trying to parse:

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the shortcut to DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
 */
defined('DS') or define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

/**
 * Foo
 * 
 * @return bool
 * @access public
 */
function foo()
{
    return true;
}
```

I want to match any function with an @access public tag, but in this case the match starts at the DS constant's comment.  I thought the `(?<! \*/)` would exclude it matching the closing comment tag of the DS comment.

What am I missing?

Comment: Out of curiosity, would it be more robust to use the [PHP Tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) to get the doc comments, then just regex the contents of the comment?

Comment: @bishop easier, shorter code?

Comment: Shorter, probably not, but I think more bullet proof and maintainable.  See @CasimiretHippolyte answer for a great example of what I was talking about.  Of course, if you have something that works now... well, "if it ain't broke, don't fix it..."

Comment: @bishop, I looked more into token_get_all(), but once you boil it down to looping through the tokens looking for T_DOC_COMMENT, followed by if statements for T_PUBLIC, T_STATIC, T_FUNCTION, function name, T_VARIABLE, checking for T_WHITESPACE etc, you're doing EXACTLY what the regex is doing.  So I wouldn't call it more robust, easier, or shorter.  In the end, the pattern I have (below) works great and spit out a nice array of exactly what I need.

Comment: Yep, but I believe the tokenized approach to be more maintainable.  Those regex are monsters!  However, what works works, period.  Glad you got the solution you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11640500/1448147) by @bishop, I found an example using negative lookahead that works for me.

I changed

`.+?(?<! \*/)`

to

`(?:(?! \*/).)+?`

So the full pattern is now:

`/\*\*(?:(?! \*/).)+?@access public.+? \*/\s+?function\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\(`

EDIT:

Full pattern that also matches function types and parameters:

`(?<full>[\t ]*?/\*\*(?:(?! \*/).)+?@access public(?:(?! \*/).)+? \*/\s+?(?:public |protected |private )??(?:static )??function\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\(.*?\))`

And class matching:

`(?<full>(?<indent>[\t ]*?)/\*\*(?:(?! \*/).)+?@access public.+? \*/\s+?(?:abstract )??class\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s??.*?{)`

Answer (score 0):

A negative lookbehind must be of fixed length. It sounds like you would be better served using some sort of DocBlock parser. There are numerous solutions available.

Comment: [Sometimes you can work around that limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640447/regexps-variable-length-lookbehind-assertion-alternatives), though.

Comment: @bishop My favorite is reversing the string and using a look behind. +1

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: (: !oot ineM

Comment: Note that his lookbehind has a fixed length.

Answer (score 0):

With the [`token_get_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) function:

```
$tokens = token_get_all($code);
$result = array();

foreach ($tokens as $k=>$token) {
    switch ($token[0]):
        case T_DOC_COMMENT:
            $isPublic = strpos($token[1], '@access public');
            break;

        case T_FUNCTION:
            $isFunction = true;
            break;

        case T_WHITESPACE:
            break;

        case T_STRING:
            if ($isFunction && $isPublic) $result[] = $token[1];

        default:
            $isFunction = false;
    endswitch;
}    

print_r($result);
```

To have an idea of what you can extract with the tokenizer, I suggest you to put the following code in the foreach loop, under the `endswitch;`:

```
if ($isPublic && isset($token[1]))
    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", $token[0],
                           token_name($token[0]),
                           strtr($token[1], "\n", ' ')
                           );
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to capture the comment, function type (e.g. public static) and function parameters as well.

Comment: @Sarke: see my edit, I think that with these elements you will be able to find what you want.