# How to parse/substitute part of a string given a starting matching condition in python?

Tags: python, regex

assume I have this string

```
text='bla1;\nbla2;\nbla3;\n#endif\nbla4;'
```

I want to define a method which removes all '\n' **except** if a '\n' is preceded by a string *starting* with '#' or '\n' follows '#', so the result of the process should be:

```
text2='bla1;bla2;bla3;\n#endif\nbla4;'
```

Is there a simple way to do this in python using regex?

(Note: is it clear to me how to avoid \n followed by #, using negative lookbehind, i.e. r'\n+(?!#)' but the challenge is how to identify a \n preceded by a string starting with #)

The challenge is:
**how to deal with a positive lookbehind with variable-length strings in python?**

Comment: So if an `\n` is preceded by a `#` then it should be left untouched. In your example also the following `\n` after `endif` is left. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes it is intentional (as described in the question), but I mainly care about the \n proceeded by a word starting with #

Comment: why is the challenge btw ? where have you used positive lookbehind ?

Comment: the moment I say that \n should not come after an arbitrary length string starting with #. I think this shows the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640447/regexps-variable-length-lookbehind-assertion-alternatives

Answer (score 1):

find :  `(#[a-z]+\\n)|\\n(?!#)`

and replace with : '\1'

output : `bla1;bla2;bla3;\n#endif\nbla4;`

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/uO8wH2

This will keep all the `\n` newline chars which have a preceding word starting with `#` or are followed by a hash.

HTH

Comment: Thx, but I am not sure this works in python, see http://regex101.com/r/uO8wH2#python

Comment: the problem in the above example is that result is 'bla1;\nbla2;\nbla3;\n#endif\nbla4;' i.e. the \n before bla2 and bla3 did not disappear. I think the reason is that python has problems in doing a positive lookbehind with non fixed-length strings.

Comment: @Mannaggia the result is the same in python check your link in the output section. see the Substitution result

Comment: The link might work, but I cannot reproduce this in python, e.g. seems not to work using re, perhaps I should try with regex package (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640447/regexps-variable-length-lookbehind-assertion-alternatives)