# Positive lookbehind followed by comma separated list

Tags: regex

I'm looking to see if there is a way to get a match group for each of a comma separated list after a positive lookbehind.

For example

```
#summertime swimming, running, tanning
```

Regex (so far)

```
(?<=#summertime\s)(.+)
```

Returns

```
["swimming, running, tanning"]
```

Desired Results

```
["swimming", "running", "tanning"]
```

Comment: I think you're better off splitting the string you currently get with `, `.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php you could do this through PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)`,

```
(?:^(?:(?!#summertime).)*$|^.*?#summertime)(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xN8eU3/8)

Comment: The problem with this that it will even match `swimming, running, tanning` whether there is `#summertime` or not...

Answer (score 1):

The classical way to solve this in PCRE/perl is to use [`\K` escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13542950) and the [`\G` anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21971701):

```
(?:                 # non-capturing group
   \#summertime\b   # match #summertime
   |                # or
   \G(?<!^),        # a comma not at the beginning of string and match it only if it's after the last match
)                   # closing the non-capturing group
\s*                 # some optional whitespaces
\K                  # forget what we matched so far
[^\s,]+             # match anything that's not a whitespace nor a comma one or more times
```

Some notes on the regex:

- I used the `x` modifier for white spacing mode.
- You might need to use the `g` modifier to match all depending on the language. In php you will need to use `preg_match_all()`.
- I escaped the hashtag in `#summertime` because the hashtag is meant for comments in white spacing mode.
- `\G(?<!^)` is a classical way of matching from the last point and not from the beginning of string/line. You might also see it in this form `\G(?!^)` or `(?!^)\G`. Remember, it's all zero-width.
- `\K` is [*awesome*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640447/regexps-variable-length-lookbehind-assertion-alternatives/11640500#11640500).
- I used `[^\s,]+` but you might as well use `\w+` or what ever suits your needs.
- A bit late but you might as well use your own solution and then split by `\s*,\s*`

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/lQ6vE0/1)</kbd>