# Positive Lookbehind with commas separated list

Tags: java, regex, lookbehind, regex-lookarounds

I am a Java developer and I am new to Regex, I have similar problem as [here in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541106/positive-lookbehind-followed-by-comma-separated-list) . I have 2 issues,

- SKIP does not work in Java
- I started following the second approach as per this [Regex link](https://regex101.com/r/lQ6vE0/1) but my use case is as below,

if I have a string like,

```
It is very nice in summer and in summer time we swim, run, tan
```

It should extract based on Positive lookbehind, "summer time we", it should extract, [smim, run, tan] as an array.

I am stuck here, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, a regex cannot by itself return an array.

But, this regex will return the values you want using a `find()` loop:

```
(?<=summer time we |\G(?<!^), )\w+
```

It is almost identical to the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25546942/5221149) that you referred to.

In Java 9+, you can create array like this:

```
String s = "It is very nice in summer and in summer time we swim, run, tan";
String[] results = Pattern.compile("(?<=summer time we |\\G(?<!^), )\\w+")
                          .matcher(s).results().map(MatchResult::group)
                          .toArray(i -> new String[i]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
```

*Output*

```
[swim, run, tan]
```

In Java 5+, you can do it with a `find()` loop:

```
String s = "It is very nice in summer and in summer time we swim, run, tan";
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=summer time we |\\G(?<!^), )\\w+");
for (Matcher m = regex.matcher(s); m.find(); )
    resultList.add(m.group());
String[] results = resultList.toArray(new String[resultList.size()]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
```

Comment: I have one more question `It is very nice in summer and in summer time we swim, run, tan, or walk, talk` is there a way to extract [swim, run, tan, walk, talk] . Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Krishna Yes. Try **learning regex** and see if you can modify the regex above, instead of asking us to write your code for you.