# Negative lookahead followed by spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I can't figure out reverse negative lookup.
Suppose I have a text

```
qwe  abc
qwe abc
abc
```

and I want to find all `abc` which is not going after `qwe`, which might be followed by any amount of spaces.

```
(?<!qwe)\s*?(abc)
```

Matches everything. I assumed it would be something like "match arbitrary amount of spaces followed by `abc` if there's no `qwe` in front of it"

I tried also

```
qwe|(abs)
```

approach, but it does not work for me. Although groups are empty for the cases where I do not want match to work, I don't really get how do I use it with `re.sub` function (which need to). Even though groups are empty, `re.sub` does replace the string.

Env: python 3

Comment: You could do it like this with the regex module instead of re `(?<!qwe\s*)abc` and place the `\s*` in the lookbehind. Else you can use `qwe\s*abc|(abc)` with a capture group. https://regex101.com/r/JNzeGi/1

Comment: You can use this module https://pypi.org/project/regex/

Comment: This would be a variable-length lookbehind, which is not supported. Otherwise @Thefourthbird is right, `(?<!qwe\s*)abc` would do the trick. Trying to come up with a workaround.

Comment: Another approach is https://regex101.com/r/JNzeGi/1

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/q/31564195/187808 there was a comment by  @jonrsharpe to use the `regex` module (instead of the `re`), so you'll have variable-length lookbehind. And then `(?<!qwe\s*)abc` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a lookbehind here. Just stick with a negative lookahead that allows dynamic length assertions:

```
^(?!.*qwe\s+abc).*abc
```

Or with word boundaries to make sure `qwe` and `abc` are complete words.

```sh
^(?!.*\bqwe\s+abc\b).*\babc\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EgE0ZY/1)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!.*qwe\s+abc)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if we have `qwe` followed by 1+ whitespaces followed by `abc` is found anywhere in the line
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters
- `abc`: Match `abc`

Comment: Just one thing I want to mention: 
As far as I understand, lookahead demands something to be matched before actual lookahead. 
E.g.  (?<!qwe) did not seem to work, while ^(?<!qwe) did. Could you please clarify that?

Comment: Please understand that `(?<!...)` is a lookbehind and `(?!...)` is a lookahead. What I suggested in my answer is a `lookahead`. I would suggest [this very good tutorial on look-arounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can find an interesting article on "The Best Regex Trick" [here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) where you would first have to match what you *don't* want using alternations. Then capture what you *do* want inside a capture group.

The syntax would be: `MatchWhatYouDon'tWant|(MatchWhatYouDoWant)`. In your particular case we can use some extra syntax using word-boundaries and a non-capturing group to nest the alternation in:

```
\b(?:qwe\b\s+abc|(abc))\b
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kArsav/1)

- `\b` - Word-boundary.
- `(?:` - Open non-capturing group:

  - `qwe\b\s+abc` - Match "qwe" literally followed by a word-boundary, 1+ whitespace characters and "abc".
  - `|` - Or:
  - `(abc)` - Match "abc" within the 1st capturing group.
  - `)` - Close non-capturing group.
- `\b` - Word-boundary.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you match `abc` in group 1 for all 3 examples, is that your pattern `(?<!qwe)\s*?(abc)` asserts at the current position that what is directly to the left is not `qwe` and then matches optional whitespace chars.

This assertion is true for the first 2 examples at the position after the space that follows `qwe`. The pattern can move to that position where the assertion is true, because it can match a whitespace char making the assertion true at that position.

The third example get a match as there is no `qwe` present at the left.

**Note** that for example there will be no match for `qweabc` as there is no room for a whitespace char to be matched making the assertion true.

---

`re` does not support variable length lookbehinds, but the [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) `regex` module does.

```
(?<!qwe\s*)abc
```

- `(?<!qwe\s*)` Positive lookbehind to assert that directly to the left is not qwe followed by optional whitespace chars.
- `abc` Match literally (You don't need the group anymore)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PqDyoJ/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##LU07DsIwDN1zCpMpQVUlKBMCcRBgCFWaZsgHOwg4fXBK3@Jnv4/zt8wpDrX6kBMWQOvsRwgq6KMjOMNVPt8WwDzGnexgWZjvG@c5rDemB3kX2ZRiMXIMpbqcNqzcaKtZlUJMCYHAR1jLjwIYoZnb056swXFWa0cHpBeDnyD8rQ2Zo0WF3mF6ZaV1rT8)