# grep: combine negative match with After (search for protein sequences that do not contain the word fragment)

Tags: grep, fasta

I have a fasta sequence and I want to filter all those out that have the word Fragment in the header.

I thought I could use `grep` with `-A 1` (because the protein sequence is always on one line) with `-i` (in case fragment is not written capitalized) and use that with `-v`, but somehow inversing the result does not work as expected.

```
>tr|A0A534K2W8|A0A534K2W8_9EURY Epoxide hydrolase 1 (Fragment) OS=Euryarchaeota archaeon OX=2026739 GN=E6K10_05355 PE=4 SV=1 
MSNTPDFNRR...
>tr|A0A4S3JUN3|A0A4S3JUN3_9EURO AB hydrolase-1 domain-containing protein OS=Aspergillus tanneri OX=1220188 GN=ATNIH1004_010243 PE=4 SV=1
MRDKYTPATL...
>tr|B1AQP8|B1AQP8_HUMAN Epoxide hydrolase 1 (Fragment) OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=EPHX1 PE=1 SV=1
MWLEILLTSV...
>tr|B1AQP9|B1AQP9_HUMAN Epoxide hydrolase 1 (Fragment) OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=EPHX1 PE=1 SV=1
MWLEILLTSV...
>tr|Q6FGZ3|Q6FGZ3_HUMAN EPHX1 protein (Fragment) OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=EPHX1 PE=2 SV=1
MWLEILLTSV...
>tr|A0A2G8L4U1|A0A2G8L4U1_STIJA Putative epoxide hydrolase 1-like OS=Stichopus japonicus OX=307972 GN=BSL78_07808 PE=4 SV=1
MVHGWPGSFY...
```

If I want to keep the sequences with *Fragment*, it is working fine

```sh
grep -i "fragment" -A 1 test.fasta                                             
>tr|A0A534K2W8|A0A534K2W8_9EURY Epoxide hydrolase 1 (Fragment) OS=Euryarchaeota archaeon OX=2026739 GN=E6K10_05355 PE=4 SV=1 
MSNTPDFNRR...
--
>tr|B1AQP8|B1AQP8_HUMAN Epoxide hydrolase 1 (Fragment) OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=EPHX1 PE=1 SV=1
MWLEILLTSV...
>tr|B1AQP9|B1AQP9_HUMAN Epoxide hydrolase 1 (Fragment) OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=EPHX1 PE=1 SV=1
MWLEILLTSV...
>tr|Q6FGZ3|Q6FGZ3_HUMAN EPHX1 protein (Fragment) OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=EPHX1 PE=2 SV=1
MWLEILLTSV...
```

but if I want to inverse the match, this is the result.

```sh
grep -i "fragment" -A 1 -v test.fasta
MSNTPDFNRR...
>tr|A0A4S3JUN3|A0A4S3JUN3_9EURO AB hydrolase-1 domain-containing protein OS=Aspergillus tanneri OX=1220188 GN=ATNIH1004_010243 PE=4 SV=1
MRDKYTPATL...
>tr|B1AQP8|B1AQP8_HUMAN Epoxide hydrolase 1 (Fragment) OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=EPHX1 PE=1 SV=1
MWLEILLTSV...
>tr|B1AQP9|B1AQP9_HUMAN Epoxide hydrolase 1 (Fragment) OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=EPHX1 PE=1 SV=1
MWLEILLTSV...
>tr|Q6FGZ3|Q6FGZ3_HUMAN EPHX1 protein (Fragment) OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=EPHX1 PE=2 SV=1
MWLEILLTSV...
>tr|A0A2G8L4U1|A0A2G8L4U1_STIJA Putative epoxide hydrolase 1-like OS=Stichopus japonicus OX=307972 GN=BSL78_07808 PE=4 SV=1
MVHGWPGSFY...
```

Any ideas where I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `-v` cannot be used with context switches. If you have `GNU grep` with `PCRE`, then you can use a complicated regex:

```sh
grep --no-group-separator -xiP -A 1 '>((?!fragment).)+'
```

Note the use `--no-group-separator` to avoid `--` between different matches. `-P` enables `PCRE`. `-x` ensures whole line is matched. `>((?!fragment).)+` ensures `fragment` is not present in lines starting with `>` (See [Variable-length lookbehind-assertion alternatives for regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640447/variable-length-lookbehind-assertion-alternatives-for-regular-expressions) for more explanation)

But, you are better off with `awk` for such cases:

```sh
# with GNU awk
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/^>/ && !/fragment/{f=2} f && f--'
# any awk
awk '/^>/ && tolower($0) !~ /fragment/{f=2} f && f--'
```

Here, `f=2` is `1` greater than number of lines you need after the match. `/^>/ && !/fragment/` will only match lines starting with `>` and NOT containing `fragment`

See also [lines around matching regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern) for more such examples.